# how to make lucene be case-insensitive

Tags: java, lucene

By default word "Word" and "word" are not the same. How can I make Lucene be case-insensitive?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest approach is lowercasing all searchable content, as well as the queries. See the  [`LowerCaseFilter`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/LowerCaseFilter.html) documentation. You could also use `Wildcard` queries for case insensitive search since it bypasses the `Analyzer`.

You can store content in different fields to capture different case configurations if preferred.

Comment: a line or two of sample source code can make your answer complete

Answer (score 7):

The `StandardAnalyzer` applies a `LowerCaseFilter` that would make "Word" and "word" the same. You could simply pass that to your uses of `IndexWriter` and `QueryParser`. E.g. a few line snippets:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, analyzer, true, mlf);
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, field, analyzer);
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to using the `StandardAnalyzer`, which includes `LowerCaseFilter` and filters for common English words (such as "the"), you should also ensure you build your document using `TextField`s, not `StringField` which are for exact searches.

Answer (score 0):

Add LowerCaseFilterFactory to your fieldType for that field in Schema.xml. Example,

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer type="index">
                <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            </analyzer>

            <analyzer type="query">
                <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
```

Comment: great answer but the question is about Lucene, which doesn't have a schema like Solr does