# Zend Search Lucene - How do you make your query case insensitive?

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene

It seems to me that Zend Search Lucene is default to case sensitive search. Is there a way to change this so that all queries are case insensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend Search Lucene should default to case-insensitive (from documentation):

> You can assign your own text analyzer or choose it from the set of
>   predefined analyzers: `Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_Text`
>   and `Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_Text_CaseInsensitive`
>   (default). Both of them interpret tokens as sequences of letters.
>   `Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_Text_CaseInsensitive`
>   converts all tokens to lower case.

You might have

```
Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault(
    new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_Text()
);
```

Set somewhere, which is switching it to case sensitive. You can try to find and remove that, or [switch analyzers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.search.lucene.extending.html).

Comment: Yeah I thought that it defaulted to case-insensitive but when I tried searching, it was case-sensitive. Will try your solution

Comment: I var_dumped the default Analyzer and sure enough, it is Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_Text_CaseInsensitive. However, the search still is case-sensitive. Here are some things that I speculate that might cause the problem, (1)index insertion process
(2)type of the index fields

Comment: It looks like there may be some useful information here (similar question) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512803/how-to-make-lucene-be-case-insensitive

Comment: I outputted the default Analyzer using  

`Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::getDefault()`  

and I got this  

`Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_Text_CaseInsensitive Object  
(  
    [_position:Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_Text:private] =>   
    [_filters:Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common:private] => Array  
        (  
            [0] => Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_TokenFilter_LowerCase Object  
                (  
                )  
        )  
    [_input:protected] =>   
    [_encoding:protected] =>   
)`  

Seems to be defaulting to lowercase