# Lucene.NET version 4.8 beta casing issue

Tags: lucene.net

I'm using Lucene.NET version 4.8 (beta) for a little search task in a solution I'm doing, but have problems searching case insensitive. I know that Lucene isn't case insensitive, but when using the StandardAnalyzer, it should lowercase the data stored (according to the documentation here [StandardAnalyzer](https://lucenenetdocs.azurewebsites.net/api/Lucene.Net.Analysis/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer.html)), as long as you make sure the queries are done right.

So any idea what I'm doing wrong here? I've stored the data "Kirsten" in a field in 4 different documents, and when searching for (lowercased) "kirsten" I get no hits, but when searching for "Kirsten" I get the expected 4.

Here's my query code:

```
        query = query.ToLowerInvariant();
        BooleanQuery q = new BooleanQuery {
            new BooleanClause(new WildcardQuery(new Term(FieldNames.Name, query + WildcardQuery.WILDCARD_STRING)), Occur.SHOULD),
            new BooleanClause(new WildcardQuery(new Term("mt-year", query)), Occur.SHOULD),
            new BooleanClause(new WildcardQuery(new Term("mt-class", query + WildcardQuery.WILDCARD_STRING)), Occur.SHOULD)
        };
```

And the issue is that the users would always write the lowercase version, and expect it to find both lower- and upper-case.

Comment: You have to show us, how you are creating your document. You are using `TextField` or `StringField`? Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32011823/7225096

Comment: That seems indeed to be the issue! I was using StringField, and I should be using TextField it seems! It's been too long since I worked with Lucene.NET it seems! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Peska wrote in the comments, this was a case of using StringField instead of TextField when adding the document (and data) to Lucene.

Once I switched to using TextField, everything worked as expected.

Comment: If the solution exists within another answer (as it does in this case), we don't post an answer, we use the built-in "Vote/Flag to close as a duplicate".